# Find if IP address is in range of addresses

Tags: python

I am trying to build a service responsible for geo location of IP addresses. The open database of IP addresses is a CSV file of the following format: starting_ip, ending_ip, region

So I was thinking about converting IPs to integers, and trying to see if a given integer is within ranges of starting and ending... However at this point I don't quite see how this comparison can be performed in an efficient way, taking into account the size of 500K entries.

At first I was trying to load everything into memory using the following dict:

```
{(ip_start, ip_end): 'region', ....}
```

But at this point I don't see how to find a key in this dict by IP address.

Comment: Well if the ips are in order you can have `O(log n)` lookups using bisect, use the start ip to see where the ip would land after and see if it is in the range of start and end ip, you might also find a database useful where you use the start ip as the primary key which will be indexed

Comment: How does one convert an IP address to an integer?

Comment: @cricket_007 `int(ip.replace(".",""))`, presuming ipv4

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That won't work... 12.34.1.1 == 123.4.1.1 in that scheme. For A.B.C.D, it would more likely be `A*(256**3) + B*(256**2) + C*256 + D`.

Comment: @glibdud, it converts an ip to an int, whether it works for what the OP is doing is another story. A simpler solution would be `tuple(map(int, ip.split(".")))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I assumed that much, but I was thinking that could cause problems when the values have leading zeros. You don't typically write `8.8.8.8` as `8.008.008.008`

Comment: @cricket_007, yes, in the OP's case converting  to `ip =  tuple(map(int, ip.split("."))) ` would allow correct comparisons as tuples are compared  lexicographically

Comment: It's done already. E.g. netaddr lib has it out of the box (I mean ips conversion)

Comment: @OlegTarasenko. personally I would use a tuple, the end result would be the same

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the ranges are non-overlapping, you could sort them once by `ip_start` and then use binary search to find a candidate range. Once you've found a candidate range, all you have to do is check whether the IP address falls between `ip_start` and `ip_end`.

You could use the built-in [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module to perform the binary search.

This gives `O(logn)` lookup cost.

Comment: Can you sketch is a bit, so it's easier to understand the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you persist the data once sorted in whatever usable format you like but using a [sortedtcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/introduction.html) *SortedDict* will allow you to do the comparison in *log n* time once you have a sorted collection, sorted by the start ip:

```
import csv
from sortedcontainers import sorteddict

with open("ips.csv") as f:
    ips = ["192.168.43.102", "10.10.145.100", "192.168.1.1", "192.168.43.99","127.0.0.1"]
    reader = csv.reader(f)
     # Use start ip as the key, creating tuple or using netaddr to turn into an int
    sorted_dict = sorteddict.SortedDict((tuple(map(int, sip.split("."))),(eip, rnge)) for sip, eip, rnge in reader)

    for ip in ips:
        # do the same for the ip you want to search for
        ip = tuple(map(int, ip.split(".")))
         # bisect to see where the ip would land
        ind = sorted_dict.bisect(ip) - 1
        start_ip = sorted_dict.iloc[ind]
        end_ip = tuple(map(int, sorted_dict[sorted_dict.iloc[ind]][0].split(".")))
        print(start_ip, ip, end_ip)
        print(start_ip <= ip <= end_ip)
```

If we run the code on a test file:

```
In [5]: !cat ips.csv
192.168.43.100,192.168.43.130,foo
192.168.27.1,192.168.27.12,foobar
192.168.1.1,192.168.1.98,bar
192.168.43.131,192.168.43.140,bar
10.10.131.10,10.10.131.15,barf
10.10.145.10,10.10.145.100,foob

In [6]: import csv

In [7]: from sortedcontainers import sorteddict

In [8]: with open("ips.csv") as f:
   ...:         ips = ["192.168.43.102", "10.10.145.100", "192.168.1.1", "192.168.43.99","127.0.0.1"]
   ...:         reader = csv.reader(f)
   ...:         sorted_dict = sorteddict.SortedDict((tuple(map(int, sip.split("."))),(eip, rnge)) for sip, eip, rnge in reader)
   ...:         for ip in ips:
   ...:                 ip = tuple(map(int, ip.split(".")))
   ...:                 ind = sorted_dict.bisect(ip) - 1
   ...:                 start_ip = sorted_dict.iloc[ind]
   ...:                 end_ip = tuple(map(int, sorted_dict[sorted_dict.iloc[ind]][0].split(".")))
   ...:                 print(start_ip,ip, end_ip)
   ...:                 print(start_ip <= ip <= end_ip)
   ...:         
(192, 168, 43, 100) (192, 168, 43, 102) (192, 168, 43, 130)
True
(10, 10, 145, 10) (10, 10, 145, 100) (10, 10, 145, 100)
True
(192, 168, 1, 1) (192, 168, 1, 1) (192, 168, 1, 98)
True
(192, 168, 27, 1) (192, 168, 43, 99) (192, 168, 27, 12)
False
(10, 10, 145, 10) (127, 0, 0, 1) (10, 10, 145, 100)
False
```

You could also  modify [bisect_right](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py) to only consider the first elements and use a regular python list:

```
def bisect_right(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi) // 2
        if x < a[mid][0]:
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid + 1
    return lo

with open("ips.csv") as f:
    ips = ["192.168.43.102", "10.10.145.100", "192.168.1.1", "192.168.43.99", "127.0.0.1"]
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    sorted_data = sorted(((tuple(map(int, sip.split("."))), eip, rnge) for sip, eip, rnge in reader))
    for ip in ips:
        ip = tuple(map(int, ip.split(".")))
        ind = bisect_right(sorted_data, ip) - 1

        ip_sub = sorted_data[ind]
        start_ip, end_ip, _ = sorted_data[ind]
        end_ip = tuple(map(int, end_ip.split(".")))
        print(start_ip, ip, end_ip)
        print(start_ip <= ip <= end_ip)
```

The result will be the same, I would imagine using a SortedDict is almost certainly faster as the bisect is done at the c level.

Answer (score 0):

The [`netaddr` package](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has an [`IPSet` class](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#netaddr.IPSet) that should help with this in a reasonably optimal way.

```py
from netaddr import IPRange, IPSet
# 1. Your CSV data
rows = [
    ('14.2.0.0', '14.2.255.255', 'bar'),
    ('24.2.1.0', '24.2.1.120', 'baz'),
    ('30.2.0.0', '30.2.3.3', 'bar'),
    ('30.3.0.0', '30.3.127.255', 'bar'),
    # ...
]

# 2. Create region -> IPSet mapping. This may be relatively slow.
regions = {}
for start_ip, stop_ip, region in rows:
    regions.setdefault(region, IPSet())
    regions[region].add(IPRange(start_ip, stop_ip))

# 3. Find a matching region for a given address. This will be fast.
def find_region(address):
    for region, ip_set in regions.items():
        if address in ip_set:
            return region
    return None

# 4. Demonstration
print(find_region('14.2.50.50'))  # Prints bar
print(find_region('8.8.8.8'))  # Prints None
```